# Efficient ways of numerically calculating eigenenergies?

Tags: computational-physics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I want to calculate the eigenenergies of the ground state, first excited state and second excited state for the Hamiltonian:

$$ H = (1-s)H_x + sH_z$$

for $s=0, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 1$. The Hamiltonian $H_z$ is diagonal, and the other one $H_x=\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_x^i$. $N$ is typically around 10-30.

My current method is to formulate $H_z$ and $H_x$ as scipy DIA sparse matrices, calculate $H$ from them and use scipy.sparse.eigsh to calculate the lowest 3 eigenenergies.

However, once N approaches 20, it's really taking a toll on the performance of the computer. Is there anything I missed that can help lower the memory consumption or make the computation faster?

EDIT: To clarify, $H$, $H_z$ and $H_x$ are all $2^N$ dimensional (the system is a N-qubit system).

Comment: Which is slower, the creation of the $H$ matrix, or the call to `scipy.sparse.eigsh`? If it is the latter, you likely have to look for some other basis in which to express your system...

Comment: I ran a quick test for a specific case of N=15, s=0.5: $H_z$ formulation takes 0.14 s, $H_x$ formulation takes 8.89 s, make $H$ from $H_z$ and $H_x$ takes 6.25 s, and using `scipy.sparse.eigsh` to calculate the lowest 3 eigenenergies of $H$ takes 76.63 s. But I don't think there would be any better basis since one of the components $H_z$ is already diagonal.

Comment: What is the dimensionality of $H$?

Comment: $H$, $H_z$ and $H_x$ are all $2^N$ dimensional (N-qubit system)

Comment: Since the complexity of diagonalization is in practice $O(d^3) = O(2^{3N})$, I don't think there is a way to make your code more efficient, as the diagonalization is already your bottleneck, and you are using a (hopefully well optimized) built-in method to do it.

Comment: AFAIK the complexity of eigsh is $O(d^2)=O(2^{2N})$ when we only want to obtain the lowest k eigenvalues, but your point still stands. Maybe I'll look into methods that are more optimized, or methods that can be parallelized.